# Off-diagonal terms of a frequency response matrix

Tags: classical-mechanics, fourier-transform, frequency, coupled-oscillators

If I have coupled system of two harmonic oscillators.

$$\ddot{x}_1+\Gamma\dot{x}_1+kx_1-kx_2=0$$

$$\ddot{x}_2+\Gamma\dot{x}_2+kx_2-kx_1=0.$$

Then I can fourier transform the equations of motion and get the Impedance matrix.
$$\begin{pmatrix} -\omega^2+i\Gamma\omega+k & -k\\ -k & -\omega^2+i\Gamma\omega+k \end{pmatrix}.$$

In concise form

$$Z[\omega]X[\omega]=F[\omega].$$

The inverse of $Z[\omega]$ matrix gives us Frequency Response matrix in control systems.

The zeroes and poles of the diagonal elements give us an idea about the resonance frequency in the system.

What does off diagonal terms of this matrix represent?

Moreover, if this off-diagonal term is imaginary what would it mean?

Comment: I don’t see the mass in your transformation?

Comment: The off diagonal are the eigen frequency $\omega ^{2}=\dfrac{k}{m}$, but in time domain you have 2 frequencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They characterize the response in one of the circuits triggered by the signal in the other. E.g., if $F(\omega)$ has only one component:
$$F(\omega) = (f_1(\omega),0),$$
Then the responses in the two circuits will be given by
$$x_1(\omega) = \Theta_{11}(\omega)f_1(\omega),\\
x_2(\omega) = \Theta_{21}(\omega)f_1(\omega),$$
where $\Theta(\omega)$ is the matrix inverse of $Z(\omega)$.

Comment: Just one more issue I am stuck at, as I have asked in the question. What does it mean for the off diagonal term to be imaginary? If one off diagonal term is imaginary and the other real, can I say signal is being transferred in only one direction ?

Comment: Since you are in Fourier space, the imaginary part is just a phase shift: $\pm i = e^{\pm\pi/2}$. In circuits it usually means that the response is delayed/advanced by a quarter period. One also often speaks of capacitive/inductive response, since capacitors and inductances have imaginary impedance (one with $i$ and the other with $-i$).

Comment: I think you are missing an i up in the exponential.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela you are right! Unfortunately one cannot correct comments...